# Unhandled Exception, cannot continue

Tags: c#, object, exception

I'm trying to add Member instances to a Race instance:

```
            race2.joinJunior(jmem);
            race2.joinJunior(jmem2);
            race2.joinJunior(jmem3);
```

the Instance of the race object (race2) has two variables that impact the following code, the first is CurrentRunners (The runners currently on the race) and limitRace (The limit of racers allowed to join the race in total)

```
public override void joinJunior(JuniorMember jm)
        {
            junior = jm;

            if (jm != null)
            {
                //Increment the current members on the race by 1.
                currentRunners++;    

                    if (currentRunners > limitRace)
                    {

                        throw new Exception(junior.FirstName + " would be this races: " + currentRunners + "th runner. This race can only take: " + limitRace);

                    }  
            }
          }
```

My issue is, when I add the third member (jmem3) my program cannot progress instead of throwing the exception.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do mean by "my program cannot progress"?

Comment: So you want it to throw the exception, but instead it doesn't step into the `if` block? What value is `limitRace` and I assume `currentRunners` is `3` by this point?

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing exception from the if block. It needs to be handled somewhere. I would recommend showing a message instead of exception.

If you really want to throw exception, you need to handle that in your code.

You could use something like this:

```
public override void joinJunior(JuniorMember jm)
{
if(jm != null && currentRunners < limitRace){

// Add runner to the list or collection

currentRunners++;
}
else{
// Show message that list of runners is full. This will require you to change the return type of your method or add out parameters
}
}
```

In case you go with exception:

```
    public override void joinJunior(JuniorMember jm)
    {
    if(jm != null && currentRunners < limitRace){

    // Add runner to the list or collection

    currentRunners++;
    }
    else{
    // throw your own exception type (you will need to create this class)
    throw new LimitExceededException("Some message here.");
    }
    }
```

In the caller method, you will need something like this:

```
    try{
                race2.joinJunior(jmem);
                race2.joinJunior(jmem2);
                race2.joinJunior(jmem3);
    }
catch(LimitExceededException ex){
// handle, replace or rethrow as per your application needs
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it, wasn't handling the exception in my Unit Testing Class.